# asynctask read blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, android-asynctask, single-threaded

```
private byte[] sendCommand (byte[] command){
        try {
            nos.write(command);
            nos.flush();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int read;
            while ((read = nis.read(buffer, 0, 4096)) > 0 && isConnecting) {
                // Read the response
                temp_data = new byte[read];
                System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, temp_data, 0, read);
            }
```

I call sendCommand three times in my doInBackground().
I expect 13 bytes of response in after sending a first command, then one byte in my second one then about 1kB in my third one.

Question 1: The first call to sendCommand() reads 13 bytes in response but the read blocks in the while condition because there is no more data. How can I make it run without blocking?

Question 2: Is it possible to send repeated write and reads in one thread? 
Because for the second call to sendCommand(), I get the same 13 byte not 1 byte of response. I wonder if the outputstream is not sending the command properly.

Comment: I can't see any logic in your read loop that would cause it to exit. Is this your actual code, or have you edited it down?

Comment: It is my actual code. It exits when read is -1. read is 13 in the first while loop and when it's second time around it blocks for some time then exits with -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to get rid of the while loop so I read only once. I still don't understand why it would not end the while loop immediately but removing the loop works for the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Your read is blocking because you've asked it to retrieve 4k bytes. While it *may* return before reading all the requested bytes, it will block on the way to doing so. You should only attempt to read the number of bytes that you're expecting:

```
byte[] response = new byte[expectedLen];
new DataInputStream(nis).readFully(response);
return response;
```